# Relations between Stiefel-Whitney classes on mapping torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In question
[Relations between Stiefel-Whitney classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158821/relations-between-stiefel-whitney-classes)
the relations between Stiefel-Whitney classes on manifold are obtained.

My question is that **do we have additional relations between Stiefel-Whitney classes on oriented mapping torus? If yes, what are they?**

Also do we have relations between Stiefel-Whitney classes and Pontryagin classes (mod 2) on mapping torus?

(Mapping torus is a fiber bundle over $S^1$)

Comment: The tangent bundle is essentially $(n-1)$-dimensional, so $w_n=0$, and $w_*$ restrict to $w_*$ of the fiber (hence, corresponding relations there), with the kernel given by the [Wang exact sequence](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4361/cohomology-of-fibrations-over-the-circle/4428#4428). That's all I can say right out of the box, unless you are interested in something more specific.